# \centerline + \href

Tags: positioning

I want to center a hyper link, using the following commands has the same results in the created pdf file but LaTeX gives me error

```
\href{URL}{\centerline{text}}------>>> error: there's no line to end \href
\centerline{\href{URL}{text}}------>>> error: there's no line to end \centerline
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example, wrapping your code in the simplest document I could thing of gave no errors.

Comment: It is hard to see how you can get the `no line` error from `\centerline` (it almost always comes from `\\ `. `\centerline` should not be used in latex really, it is just a left-over from plain tex.

Answer (score 2):

The error `there's no line to end` is not related to `\href` or `\centerline`. *Before*, you have very likely a `\\`, which does not end a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{URL}{\centerline{text}}  
\centerline{\href{URL}{text}}
\end{document}
```

Runs fine except for an overfull `\hbox`, because the first line is too large because of the paragraph indentation.

Also keep in mind, `\centerline` is an inheritance from plain TeX, not a genuine LaTeX command. It is an `\hbox`, which does *not* start a paragraph mode. Other ways of centering are environment `center` or command `\centering`, which should be put into a group including the paragraph ending.

In the first case, the full line is made to a link including the white space to the left and right. Maybe it is not, what it is intended.